# Apt-get autocompletion

Tags: bash, apt, autocomplete, non-root-user

I am currently running 64-bit Debian Wheezy.

I am having some trouble with auto completion for apt-get. I have bash-completion installed.

If I am logged in as root in a shell, I can use auto completion for apt-get (ex: *apt-get install wicd[tab][tab*]) and it will show me all the packages that match that. But if I try to use auto completion for apt-get in another non-root user (even with sudo) it will not work at all. I can auto complete other things like file names.

Any help?

I do have the following code in my .bashrc and /etc/profile

```
 if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
      . /etc/bash_completion
 fi
```

Comment: First, check whether root and the other users have the same shell. If not, that's the reason for the different behaviour. Otherwise, try this: ‘apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames "wicd"’. Does it work? That's what bash uses to generate the completion of ‘apt-get install wicd[TAB]’.

Comment: They are both using the same shell, bash. the apt-cache command you gave me does work and shows a list of all the wicd packages. Also, what I found out is when my computer first boots up and I log into the shell for the first time ( I do not have a gui log in), the apt-get autocompletion will work with any account. But if I run my fvwm-crystal window manager with startx, then open a terminal, it will not work again with just my user account. It still works with root in fvwm-crystal.

Comment: OK, this is what can be happening. /etc/profile and .bash_profile are run on login shells. That is, when you login on the console, or when you run ‘su’. Since in those cases completion works, /etc/profile is working. What's left is ~/.bashrc. Check that the line ‘. /etc/bash_completion’ is really being executed. Put something like ‘echo OK’ before it, open a new terminal, and check it says ‘OK’.

Comment: did you ever tested ZSH ?

Comment: Your .bashrc might be completely missing; this was my case

Answer (score 8):

Your `/etc/bash_completion` file must be missing.

`sudo apt-get install bash-completion`

should solve all your problems.

Given that you already have lines uncommented in `/etc/bash.bashrc` as Faheem Mitha and others pointed out, it should work now:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Reason: The `bash-completion` package now has that file (/etc/bash_completion).
It used to be in the `bash` package, but not any more.

[info on package change](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=466140)

Comment: what should be in the **/etc/bash_completion** file? I ran the **install bash-completion** command and everything is already the latest version but my bash completion file is empty

Comment: look for a section which has "bash_completion" commented out and uncomment it, or if it doesn't exist, insert the snippet provided by n611x007

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember if this is necessary, but try uncommenting the corresponding lines from `/etc/bash.bashrc` if not already uncommented, namely

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running this:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, bash autocompletion for command parammeters is done via the `complete` command. You should have an apt-get completion script loaded by the root user bashrc (maybe /root/.bashrc), so you need root login to run it. Sudo does not load root login scripts, it just gives you privileges.

Maybe you're missing that autocompletion script for non-root users, so they don't have bash autocompletion configured for apt-get. If that is true, load that functions for users having ALL privileges within the sudoers file.